# Converting Arabic numerals to Roman numerals

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, converting, roman-numerals

These classes are part of a program I am working on to convert Arabic numerals to Roman numerals and vice-versa.  Do these classes look correct for representing objects in Java?

```
public class ArabicNumeral {
private final int value; 

public ArabicNumeral(final int value) {
    if (value < 0) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Numbers must be positive");
    } 
    this.value = value;
}

public int getThousands() {
    return getCardinalValueFor(1000);
}

public int getHundreds() {
    return getCardinalValueFor(100);
}

public int getTens() {
    return getCardinalValueFor(10);
}

public int getOnes() {
    return getCardinalValueFor(1);
}

private int getCardinalValueFor(final int divisor) {
    return value / divisor % 10;
}
}



public enum RomanNumerals { 
I("I", 1),
V("V", 5),
X("X", 10),
L("L", 50),
C("C", 100),
D("D", 500),    
M("M", 1000);

private final String symbol;
private final int value;

RomanNumerals(final String symbol, final int value) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
    this.value = value;
}

String symbol() {
    return symbol;
}

int value() {
    return value;
}

public RomanNumerals getMultipleOfFive() {
    return this.ordinal() < RomanNumerals.values().length - 1
            ? RomanNumerals.values()[this.ordinal() + 1] : null;
}

public RomanNumerals getMultipleOfTen() {
    return this.ordinal() < RomanNumerals.values().length - 1
            ? RomanNumerals.values()[this.ordinal() + 2] : null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't do an `ArabicNumeral`, too, as this is the default numeric system of java.

From a design view, I would see an object `RomanNumeral`, which is an aggregation of `RomanLiteral`objects, this `RomanLiteral`, are the constant roman string->decimal value pairs, which can't be computed.

Both classes can extend `java.lang.Number`
[image: RomanNumeral design]

**Class RomanLiteral** represents one base value of the roman numeral system, it is a String - Integer relation, e.g. "V" -> 5. `toString()` is overriden to return the `String` value.

**Class RomanNumeral**
Represents a fully roman numeral, it is an aggregate of `RomanLiteral`s, which are basic String - Integer relation, e.g. "V" -> 5, and so on.

**Attributes**

- `defaultRomanLiteralSet` this `Set` containts the basic constant `RomanLiteral`s
- `literals` this is the `List` which contains all `RomanLiteral`s that aggregate this `RomanNumeral`

**Methods**

- `RomanNumeral parseRomanNumeral(Integer)` is an analogy to [Integer#parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) this method may be static, and returns the `RomanNumeral` of the `Integer` param.
- `add(RomanNumeral)` adds an `RomanNumeral` to the current value of the object and returns it.
- `add(RomanLiteral)` adds the `RomanLiteral` to the current value of the object and returns it.
- `toString()` is overriden to return the right `String` representation of the roman numeral - there happens some calculations with the matching values in the default-set. Here actually gets the roman String calculated out of the integer value of the aggregate.

I think that would be a good useable design. I would stay quite near to the `Number` style of java, and would do my implementation and design in this direction. (analgous methods and so on..)

Answer (score 3):

- `RomanNumerals.D.getMultipleOfTen()` is `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
- RomanNumerals.D.getMultipleOfFive() is M

What does `getMultipleOfFive` mean? And why should it return 1000
   when called on 500?

- `symbol()` and `value()` should be `getSymbol()` and `getValue()` by convention.
- `symbol()` and `value()` why are they package-private? What are other classes in the package that use them?

  - Where does the conversion take place?

Objects, like everything else, are meaningful only in a context. There is not a *one-correct-representation* of an arabic numeral. Arabic numerals are default representation so you ***probably*** do not need `ArabicNumeral` at all.
only logic there is in:

```
private int getCardinalValueFor(final int divisor) {
    return value / divisor % 10;
}
```

which can be rewritten as :

```
public static int getCardinalValueFor(int value, int divisor) {
    return value / divisor % 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is about general design structure.

You have methods `getThousands()`, `getHundreds()` etc those are calling `getCardinalValueFor()` with different parameters. You don't need so many methods just to provide different parameters.

As per *Effective Java* Item number #40 (Design method signatures carefully),

> Every method should “pull its weight.” Too many methods make a class difficult to learn, use,document, test, and maintain.